# Multithreading in UI

Tags: multithreading, winforms, z-order

I have a winform from where the user starts a process with a button click and I display the running process information on another winform running on different thread. The code in the button click is as below:

```
 private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Thread th=new Thread(ShowInfoForm);
       th.Start();
       //Code for process execution
       EditInfoForm();
       th.Join();
       this.BringToFront();           
    }


private void ShowInfoForm()
    {
        infoForm = new InfoForm();
        infoForm.showBox("Process Started", infoForm.MsgLevel.INFO,ButtonOK.DISABLED);
    }
private void EditInfoForm()
    {
        infoForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => infoForm.EditBox("Process Completed", infoForm.MsgLevel.INFO,ButtonOK.ENABLED));
    }
```

Everything works fine except the `bringToFront` call on the main thread. After exiting the info form on its "OK" button click, the main form goes back in the z order. How can I resolve this?

P.S. I understand that the best practice is to keep UI in the same thread and run processes on background threads, but this is a huge bulk of code and I cannot edit it.

Comment: This is a standard problem when you display UI on another thread.  The window doesn't have any Z-order relationship with the rest of the windows that are created on the UI thread.  Above all, there's just no point in using a thread when you call Thread.Join().  Always keep UI on the UI thread, do expensive work on a worker thread.  BackgroundWorker helps you fall in the pit of success.

Comment: I am actually using a different thread because in my info form, I am using an animated gif and the frame changes in animation is not happening when that info form is running on the same thread where the process is being executed.